# KO js undifined custom function

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, checkout-page

I want to custom data render from shipping method render.
I have changed files(template in this file js):

Magento_Checkout/js/view/cart/shipping-rates.js

```
getSubfixLabel: function(){

            var label =  window.checkout.estimate_label_subfix;

            return label;
        },
```

Magento_Checkout/template/shipping-rates.html

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<form id="co-shipping-method-form" data-bind="blockLoader: isLoading, visible: isVisible()" >
    <p class="field note" data-bind="visible: (!isLoading() && shippingRates().length <= 0)">
        <!-- ko text: $t('Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time')--><!-- /ko -->
    </p>
    <fieldset class="fieldset rate" data-bind="visible: (shippingRates().length > 0)">
        <dl class="items methods" data-bind="foreach: shippingRateGroups" >
            <dd class="item-options" data-bind="foreach: { data:$parent.getRatesForGroup($data), as: 'method' }" afterRender="$parent.showEstimateLabelAfterRender">
                <div data-bind="css: {'field choice item': available, 'message error': !available} ">
                    <!-- ko ifnot: (available) -->
                    <div data-bind="text: error_message"></div>
                    <!-- /ko -->
                    <!-- ko if: (available) -->
                    <input type="radio"
                           class="radio"
                           data-bind="
                                click: $parents[1].selectShippingMethod,
                                checked: $parents[1].selectedShippingMethod,
                                attr: {
                                        value: carrier_code + '_' + method_code,
                                        id: 's_method_' + carrier_code + '_' + method_code
                                        }
                                "/>
                    <label class="label" data-bind="attr: {for: 's_method_' + carrier_code + '_' + method_code}">
                        <!-- ko text: $data.method_title --><!-- /ko -->
                        <each args="element.getRegion('price')" render="" />
                        <div data-bind="html: getSubfixLabel"></div>
                    </label>
                    <!-- /ko -->
                    <div class="estimate_shipping no-display" data-bind="attr: {id: 'label_carrier_' + method_code + '_' + carrier_code}">
                        <!-- ko text: $data.carrier_title --><!-- /ko -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </dd>
        </dl>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

I want to get data from function getSubfixLabel and render by html. However, it's showing this function undefined.

```
ReferenceError: estimate_label_subfix is not defined
```

Anyone can help me out this issues?

Answer (score 0):

First you can check this in chrome browser console, enter "window.checkout.estimate_label_subfix" and check if its set in the checkout object.

Comment: it really added. I find the problem, I must call $parent[1].getSubfixLabel() in template file. It will work

Comment: Great , if issue solved.